# 'Misconfiguration in the system' error in local R Shiny app connected to Auth0 using the Auth0 library

Tags: r, authentication, shiny, auth0, r-library

I am trying to create a simple shiny app that is connected to the Auth0 password system using the Auth0 library. Currently, I am just trying to run locally. I get an Auth0 page that says 'there could be a misconfiguration in the system or a service outage' when I try to run, but I can't figure out why. I took the following steps:

1. library(Auth0) in app
2. shinyServerAuth0(...) in app
3. created a Auth0 'regular web application' project
4. copied the Auth0 project secret, name, and username, and set it to variables in .Renviron
5. added the URLS 'http://localhost:8080, https://[redacted].shinyapps.io/' to the Callback, Logout, and Web Origin settings.
6. Saved/refreshed everything.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Is this real code? I thought the package name is `auth0` (lower-case "a"). There are likely many things that could go wrong, such as not correctly identifying the URL of the app to the auth0 servers.

Comment: Thanks, you're right about it being auth0 instead of Auth0. I just typed it incorrectly in stack.

Answer (score 2):

Update: I finally figured out what I was doing wrong. I was setting the api_url to be https://[my_name].auth0.com instead of https://[my_name].us.auth0.com. So if you use the autogenerated YML and the US url make sure to change that.

Answer (score 0):

---

## Context

A similar problem that happened to have the same solution as @Hattie35's. I'm putting it here just in case someone else comes across it.

I was about to ask the question here on StackOverflow when @Hattie35's question popped up in the suggestions.

Here you go:

---

---

### Problem

I'm trying to implement authentication to my R Shiny app using the [{auth0}](https://curso-r.github.io/auth0/) package.

I have followed [the documentation](https://curso-r.github.io/auth0/) step by step for around 10 times now but I keep getting the same error on my browser when I run the application:

```
Unknown host: thetechie.auth0.com
```

Nothing else shows on the page.

Has anyone else encountered this before? What might I be missing? I'd really appreciate any pointers in the right direction.

---

---

### Reprex

`app.R`:

```r
options(shiny.port = 8085)

library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    plotOutput("plot")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    plot(1:10)
  })
}

auth0::shinyAppAuth0(ui, server)
```

`_auth0.yml`:

```yaml
name: myApp
remote_url: ''
auth0_config:
  api_url: !expr paste0('https://', Sys.getenv('AUTH0_USER'), '.auth0.com')
  credentials:
    key: !expr Sys.getenv("AUTH0_KEY")
    secret: !expr Sys.getenv("AUTH0_SECRET")
```

`.Renviron`:

```
AUTH0_USER=thetechie
AUTH0_KEY=ClientId
AUTH0_SECRET=ClientSecret
```

Allowed Callback URLs, Allowed Logout URLs and Allowed Web Origins are all:

```
http://localhost:8085/
```

---

---

### Solution

As @Hattie35 suggested, edit the autogenerated `_auth0.yml` and add the region "part" to the `api_url`:

```yaml
name: myApp
remote_url: ''
auth0_config:
  api_url: !expr paste0('https://', Sys.getenv('AUTH0_USER'), '.us.auth0.com')
  credentials:
    key: !expr Sys.getenv("AUTH0_KEY")
    secret: !expr Sys.getenv("AUTH0_SECRET")
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same problem and getting the same error again and again whenever I tried to log in through it. But, now I find the solution and it works for me.
**Solution:**

Currently, auth0 has changed their way to write the 'clientID' and 'domain' names, etc.
Earlier, they were writing in the following way:

```
<Auth0Provider
    domain="dev-12334556767.us.auth0.com"
    clientId="abdgcfdhdfhjgjrbubrfubhbure"
    redirect_uri: window.location.origin
    >
    <AppProvider>
      <App />
    </AppProvider>
</Auth0Provider>
```

But, now things have changed now, and follow this below pattern to write the configuration of auth0:

```
<Auth0Provider
    domain="dev-12334556767.us.auth0.com"
    clientId="abdgcfdhdfhjgjrbubrfubhbure"
    authorizationParams={{
      redirect_uri: window.location.origin
    }}
  >
  <AppProvider>
    <App />
  </AppProvider>
</Auth0Provider>
```

I hope this will work for everyone. Thanks